# Use a service in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I got some problem when I'm trying to use an Angular service in the controlleur of my application.

When I'm trying to use function of my service in my controlleur, my console throw me an error :/

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {
                controlleur: 'login',
                templateUrl: 'modules/login/login.html'
            })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }]);

app.service('coreServices', [function () {
        this.helloConsole = function () {
            console.log("console services");
        };
    }]);

app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', 'coreServices', LoginController]);

    function LoginController($scope, $http, $rootScope, coreServices) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.helloConsole = coreServices.helloConsole;
        vm.helloConsole();
    }
```

```css
angular.js:13708 TypeError: vm.helloConsole is not a function
    at new LoginController
```

I link you this fiddle to show you how I do: https://jsfiddle.net/h8yaxLap/2/

The error throwed is: 
angular.js:13708 TypeError: vm.helloConsole is not a function
    at new LoginController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in your example angular will map `$location` to coreService in the injected parameters in the function. So I would go for

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', 'coreServices', LoginController]);
function LoginController($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, coreServices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change service function to return object

```
app.service('coreServices', function () {
    return { 
      helloConsole: function () {
        console.log("console services");
      }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed $location parameter for the controller
function LoginController($scope, $http, $rootScope,**$location**, coreServices)